# Switching of WLAN AP channel using iw does not work

Tags: wifi, wlan, iw

Reproduce:

start a hwsim wlan AP, let it either automatically choose a channel (i.e. don't set a channel in `hostapd.conf`) or set one in the conf file. Let's assume we have `wlan0` and the channel is `2 (2417 MHz)` - check current channel using `iw dev`. Try to switch the channel using either:

`iw dev wlan0 switch channel 5`

and

`iw dev wlan0 switch freq 2432`

response: `command failed: Invalid argument (-22)`

```
Usage:  iw [options] dev <devname> switch channel <channel> [NOHT|HT20|HT40+|HT40-|5MHz|10MHz|80MHz] [beacons <count>] [block-tx]
Options:
        --debug         enable netlink debugging
```

I tried adding `NOHT`, `HT20`, `beacon 4` and combinations of it, nothing worked.

Changing the channel using `iw dev wlan0 set channel 5` works, but in this case the interface has to be `down`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the output of `iw dev wlan0 info`

Comment: `Interface wlan0
        ifindex 22
        wdev 0x1
        addr 02:00:00:00:00:00
        ssid testap
        type AP
        wiphy 0
        channel 2 (2417 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2417 MHz
        txpower 20.00 dBm`
sry, don't know how to format it in the comment properly